# Htaccess url rewrite with xampp

Tags: .htaccess

URL : `http://localhost/test/quotes/index.php?p=top-games`

I need to rewrite this as `http://localhost/test/quotes/top-games`

How I do this using htaccess file? Please can any one give me the htaccess code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /test/quotes/index\.php?p=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /test/quotes/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/quotes/(.+)$ /test/quotes/index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```